# Does Peewee supports mysql function Date()?

Tags: python, peewee

I have below command :

```
SELECT Date(mydate),sum(price),username from shop_table where Date(mydate)>'2011-01-07' GROUP BY Date(mydate),username
```

Because the dates include the time, I convert them into 'only date' using Date() function, so regardless of hours I can understand the total amount of sales in one day.

But is there an ability in peewee using 'fn' to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just call the function with whatever parameters:

```
fn.DATE(MyModel.my_date)
```